# How to add images to image control in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I get images from TFS client in the following format :

> http://vstf:8080/tfs/test/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileNameGuid=d93fcf12-d201-4ed3-bff5-a568b2cf698f&FileName=Imag2.png

I added an image control to a table cell and set the image source as External and value as

> http://vstf:8080/tfs/test/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileNameGuid=d93fcf12-d201-4ed3-bff5-a568b2cf698f&FileName=Imag2.png

However, it just shows a red cross.

I tried this on a `WPF` application using a image control and it is working fine. How can I set the image value in `SSRS` report?

Comment: Go back to your image control and verify the image source is still external not embedded. Are you deploying the report in report server? Make sure the user have access to the  path you provided. For your test take a image from external site and test to confirm if it is not a security issue.

Comment: Yes it is external. I am testing it in my local system and I do have access.